# CUDA debug in MAC, error: "A device about to be used for compute may already be in use for graphics"

Tags: macos, cuda, gpu, nvidia

When I try to debug a `CUDA` program with mac, it gives me this error:

`"A device about to be used for compute may already be in use for graphics", and the debugging is aborted.`

I have 2 GPUs in my computer: `NVIDIA` and `Intel HD`, how this problem comes up, and how to overcome it?

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966496/nvidia-cuda-error-all-cuda-capable-devices-are-busy-or-unavailable-on-osx?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to debug on a display GPU in <s>either Linux or</s> OS X. This is clearly explained in the CUDA release notes.

Comment: CUDA 5.5 added single GPU debugging for Linux.

Comment: @RogerDahl: Thanks for the correction, I wasn't aware that was supported (although I remember Greg Smith mentioning that it was coming)

Comment: thanks very much. what should I do for debug? with single GPU debugging?

Comment: @yiru Unfortunately, on Macs pretty much the only solution is debugging remotely on a different system - or relying on printfs...

Comment: @Eugene Thank you. it's a bad news, but finally i don't have to stuck here.

Comment: @Eugene maybe it's been a long time, but " It is not possible to remotely debug a CUDA application running on Mac OS X."

Comment: @yiru No, currently there is no cuda-gdbserver on Mac. It is still possible to use Mac as a host and Linux as a target.

Answer (score 0):

It means it is only possible to "run" the code on a display GPU, instead of "debug".