# RuntimeError: CUDA error: all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, google-colaboratory

This problem has occurred to me in Google Colab. How can I fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "emnlp_final_experiments/sentiment-analysis/train_basic.py", line 286, in <module>
bert = DistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(bert_model, config=bert_config).to(device)

RuntimeError: CUDA error: all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable  
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

Line 286:

```
  if args.full_bert:
     bert = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(bert_model, config=bert_config).to(device)
  else:
     bert = DistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(bert_model, config=bert_config).to(device)
```

Of course, "Training on GPU" is printed, meaning cuda is available:

```
if args.n_gpu > 0 and torch.cuda.is_available():
    print("Training on GPU")
    device = torch.device("cuda:0")
```

Comment: Is it available, but busy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7186910/11381650 or restarting your computer, did u try?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4390160/grismar
Yeah!
"Training on GPU" prints first, but then gives an error.
I use colab GPU.

Comment: I had a similar problem recently on the cluster. It was solved by restarting the instance, but not sure how to do that on colab.

Comment: I face it with executing a special part of code. and it happens after restarting again. but executing other parts of the code doesn't raise error.